# comparing multiple values assigned to one key in two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to compare two dictionaries. Each dictionary has a key and 2 values assigned to that key. Each dictionary may be a different length.

I wish to write a loop that first checks if the keys in both dictionaries are matching. Then to check if the 1st and 2nd value in the 1st dictionary is in between the 1st and 2nd value in the second dictionary.

example dictionaries:

```
gas_dict ={{'methane': (85, 98), 'ethane': (1, 12), 'propane': (0.1, 6)...x}

scope_dict ={'methane': (35, 100), 'ethane': (0.05, 15), 'propane': (1, 11)...n}
```

where x and y <= 20 but may be different numbers.

Part of my code succeeds in checking the keys are matching:

```
for key in scope_dict.keys():
            if key in gas_dict.keys():
```

However, I'm stuck at trying to figure out how to compare the 4 values from 2 keys.

Comment: please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def range_subset(range1, range2):
    return (range1[0]>=range2[0] and range1[1]<=range2[1])

for key in dict1.keys():
    if key in dict2.keys():
        print(key)
        print(range_subset(dict1[key], dict2[key]))
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
```

Comment: the variable names are rubbish, but I'm sure you can make meaningful function/variable names in your code that will suit you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a solution to your problem:

```
def gas_in_scope(gas_dict, scope_dict):
    # For each gas
    for k, (g1, g2) in gas_dict.items():
        # Get scope values
        if k not in scope_dict:
            return False
        s1, s2 = scope_dict[k]
        # Check gas values are within the scope
        if not (s1 <= g1 <= s2 and s1 <= g2 <= s2):
            return False
    # If all values are fine then return true
    return True

print(gas_in_scope({'methane': (85,  98), 'ethane': (   1, 12)},
                   {'methane': (35, 100), 'ethane': (0.05, 15)}))
# True

print(gas_in_scope({'methane': (85,  98), 'ethane': (   1, 12), 'propane': (0.1,  6)},
                   {'methane': (35, 100), 'ethane': (0.05, 15), 'propane': (  1, 11)}))
# False
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that the scope_dict may contain more keys and values than the gas_dict. I will edit my Question.

Comment: Your answer works but returns false when there are more keys in the scope_dict. Therefore, does not execute the remaining code after this if statement.

Comment: where is such `scope_dict` defined? Show the assumptions and expected results for a given input

Comment: I have amended my original question to make this clear.

Comment: @Joey I see, thanks for the clarification, I updated that.

Comment: @Pynchia Is that question for me or OP? In my code `scope_dict` is a parameter to the function (the snippet is self-contained and can be run).